# Mysql empty value error

Tags: mysql, sql

I was use hostgator host with my site. I bought a server today. But ı have a lot of error.

My sql queries arent work. For example this sql query ;

```
INSERT INTO siparisler SET kullanici_id='2', toplam_tutar='240', kdv='43.2', tarih='1403293475', siparis_durumu='1', kargo_tutari='0', siparis_notu='', odeme_yontemi='1', kapida_odeme_bedeli='', fatura_tipi='1', fatura_tc_kimlik='29488021352', fatura_sirket_adi='', fatura_vergi_no='', fatura_vergi_dairesi='', tarih2='2014-06-20'
```

When i use empty value, this server make error. And when i dont set default value, error again. How i solve this problem ? I tried my.cnf file edit, but it doesnt work. Please help me.

My error codes are ;

```
#1364 - Field 'kargoya_verildi' doesn't have a default value  

#1265 - Data truncated for column 'kapida_odeme_bedeli' at row 1
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the error is?

Comment: #1364 - Field 'kargoya_verildi' doesn't have a default value

Comment: #1265 - Data truncated for column 'kapida_odeme_bedeli' at row 1

Comment: what about those errors is unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are not writing anything to column `kargoya_verildi`, so either add it to INSERT

```
INSERT INTO siparisler SET kargoya_verildi = '', kullanici_id='2', toplam_tutar='240', kdv='43.2', tarih='1403293475', siparis_durumu='1', kargo_tutari='0', siparis_notu='', odeme_yontemi='1', kapida_odeme_bedeli='', fatura_tipi='1', fatura_tc_kimlik='29488021352', fatura_sirket_adi='', fatura_vergi_no='', fatura_vergi_dairesi='', tarih2='2014-06-20'
```

or change column definition

```
ALTER TABLE siparisler MODIFY COLUMN kargoya_verildi VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Or whatever data type of `kargoya_verildi` is.